# ScaleGestureDetector triggers onScaleEvent with single finger touch

Tags: android

I have code that onTouchEvent passes the touch event to a member ScaleGestureDetector and if the scale GD triggers a onScaleEvent on my scale listener, I scale up the display item. If the onScale event is not triggered I treat this event as a potential drag and move the displayed item around. I have observed that on certain devices the ScaleGestureDetector triggers an onScale event for me, even if there is just a single finger touching the screen. Is this expected? What is the recommended mechanism to deal with scales and drags at the same time?

Comment: Some devices actually zoom by holding down a single finger. Are you getting this behaviour on for example Sony Ericsson?

Comment: HTC EVO 4G is the device. However my question is more basic than that. Are single finger scale gestures a bug or a valid possiblity?

Comment: I had some unexpected scaling events, but later discovered that they were caused by my palm accidentally touching a corner of the screen without me being aware of it.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm correct you're triggering mScaleGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(mEvent) with single pointer (mEvent.getPointersCount() == 1). It is supposed to be triggered with pointers greater than 1. Make sure you're triggering with pointersCount > 1 Eg.

```
if(pointersCount >1) {
     TOUCH_GESTURE_MODE = GESTURE_MODE_SCALE;
     mScaleGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(mEvent);
     return true;
}
```